# NullPointerException with dos.write

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

This code is written to record a file and return a sequence of the values from the audio file so that I can do some signal processing.
I  keep getting a null pointer exception on this line towards the bottom:

```
dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
```

Can someone explain what is wrong and what I should change?

```
package com.example.wesle.noisemachine;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReceiveScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button buttonStart, buttonStop, buttonPlay, buttonDecode;
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    private String outputFile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive_screen);

        buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);
        buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
        buttonDecode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDecode);
        buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
        buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);
        outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp";
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    mediaRecorder.prepare();
                    mediaRecorder.start();
                } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
                    System.out.println("ISE Catch");
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.out.println("IO Catch");

                }
                buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
                buttonStop.setEnabled(true);


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });

        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                mediaRecorder.stop();
                mediaRecorder.release();

                buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
                buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
                buttonStart.setEnabled(true);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(outputFile);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("E Catch");
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording Playing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        buttonDecode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //System.out.println(readFile("recording.3gp"));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Decoding", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                //initializes variables
                File file = new File(outputFile);
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
                try {
                    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                int bytesRead = 0;
                int bufferSize = 0;
                int bytesAvailable = 0;
                byte[] buffer;
                int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
                DataOutputStream dos = null;


                // create a buffer of maximum size
                try {
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                try {
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    while (bytesRead > 0){
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  //<<<<<<<HERE
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    try {
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }
                fileInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        //Code for the back button
        Button backbuttonR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backbuttonR);
        backbuttonR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ReceiveScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am very new to android, I read that article and i didn't really understand what was wrong

Comment: You haven't initialized your `dos`, it's always null `DataOutputStream dos = null;` So exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DataOutputStream dos` is never initialized in

```
buttonDecode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
```

method. Please initialize this variable to avoid `NullPointerException`.